# Import TAR archive files on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, tar, data-import

I have received a data file for PostgreSQL but I work on MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. The file format is TAR archive but I don't know how to import in on MySQL Workbench.

I read online that I have to get some connector but I have started my SQL journey very recently and I am stuck on literally step 1. I don't know what connectors are and I don't know how to connnect what I need to connect.

Please help me, If possible be as dummy proof as you can. Thank you.

I have received datafile from person who uses PostgreSQL and I am using MYSQL workbench and I am not able to open it on MYSQL because of format error.

Comment: There is no simple answer. You will have to edit the file and change it to MySQL syntax.

Comment: Install PostgreSQL on your machine and use that file to create a database.

Comment: The first step would be extracting the file(s) from the TAR. Then see what the content is. How to proceed would depend on that/those results.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for responding. How do I edit it? Do I just rename it to MySQL Workbench format?

Comment: You edit it with a text editor. You have to change the SQL statements until they work in MySQL.

Comment: @Belayer thank you for responding. The file inside the tar archive file is in .dat format. What do I do next?

Comment: ".dat" is a generic file suffix.  It does not dictate a specific content format.  So ... you will need to examine the content with a text editor to decide what to do.  Sometimes head -10 might reveal info about the source format, sometimes it will reveal the format spec for the contents, and sometimes it gives no clues at all, other than show you data, possibly in CSV form or fixed-format table.  Depending on what you have, you may need to reformat, possibly using something like AWK to assist with that. You might be lucky enough to find SQL statement.  You need to confirm compatibility.